# Postgres Sharding: Impact of creating partition on the Master Node?

Tags: postgresql

Currently I'm experimenting on Postgres Sharding. I have created multiple partitions, one (1) on the Master itself and the rest on foreign servers.

Let's assume all the shards have ~1 million rows individually and there might be more than one DB on the Master Node. Now I'm curious about whether there are any performance impact or is it a *Bad Practice* to place a shard on the Master Node. Thanks in advance for any enlightenment.

Comment: Of course there is a performance impact. What sharding method are you using (citus? regular built-in partitioning on foreign tables)? Normally you want one PostgreSQL cluster to serve as master and additional clusters as worker nodes.

Comment: I'm using the built-in partitioning. If I get it correctly, I should distribute all the shards among available worker nodes. Right?

Comment: it depends. you can place your partitions wherever you like, usually it's better for performance to have your shards on a machine with many CPUs, plenty of RAM and ultrafast storage :-)

Comment: I see. Then in contrast what would be the ideal specs for master? If I'm not placing any shards on the master cluster.

Comment: Excuse me - this is a very broad question, impossible to give any sensible answer. Generally speaking, you don't need any partitioning/sharding as long as the _hot data_ (ie., indexes and crucial part of heap) fits in shared buffers cache.